# RapidMiner and Davies-Bouldin Index

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, rapidminer

Can anyone give me an explanation about the reason why Davies-Bouldin Index is negative in RapidMiner?

I searched but found almost nothing.

Comment: Maybe RapidMiner clustered just very very bad?

Comment: It might be because other operators that try to find the optimum performance need to look for a maximum.  Davies Bouldin yields a minimum for the best clustering. Negating the value turns it into a maximum.